# Brightness and volume buttons don't work

Tags: 14.04, kde, brightness, volume-control, toshiba

I have a Toshiba Chromebook 2. I installed Ubuntu 14.04.02 few days ago and noticed that my function buttons don't work. I mostly care about the brightness and volume buttons. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so brightness works now. With audio it took me a while to figure it out but basically you need to install pulseaudio FIRST, reboot, and then install KMix and reboot again. Now it works :D

Answer (score 4):

Go to the KDE settings ("configure desktop" or "system settings") -> Shortcuts and Gestures -> Global Keyboard Shorcuts.

For volume, go to `KMix`, click "Volume Down" next to "Decrease Volume", click the box next to "Custom", then hit "Volume Down" button on your chromebook.  Do the same with "Mute" and "Volume Up".

For brightness, go to "KDE Daemon".  Set "Decrease Screen Brightness" and "Increase Screen Brightness" in the same way.

If the buttons are not detected at all, then it is likely that X11 does not support the buttons.

Comment: Okay so I clicked on global keyboard shortcuts,but can not find KMix. I did manage to get brightness working tho ! Thanks !  How do i get kmix ?

Comment: It should be in the dropdown list.  Do you have it running?  Does plasma have a volume meter?  If not, you might need to open the application launcher and type in "kmix" and launch it.  Once you do that it should run on its own from then on.  If it isn't open, that may be why your volume keys don't work, so check them before messing with the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Seems like i did not have KMix installed. I installed it thru software-center and reboot system. Now i see the program starts with the system and I managed to find it in dropdown list. I changed volume keyboard shortcuts but it doesnt work. Maybe kmix isnt working properly ?

Comment: Im trying to select master channel but tab is empty.

Comment: Are you using pulseaudio?

Comment: no im not. should i download ? im new to all this

Comment: Things will probably be easier with pulseaudio, so I would install it.

Comment: okay i will try to do that and will update. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Step #4 on this post: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-on.html describes the options to solve this problem.

The article says it is because the Keyboard target is not setup correctly.

Comment: i tried this method before but did not work for me.  I still cant manage to control volume